# I need to create a script that will check a files size, warn user, move files and link to new location

Tags: hyperlink, size, warnings, move

We are trying to keep as little end-user data on our companies thin-clients, so I need to create a script that will run when a file is saved locally. I'm completely new to power shell so I do apologize for the lack of knowledge.

Check file size

if (file size is equal or greater than "x"mb) output a warning "file is larger than allowed, moving file to you cloud drive (usually the K: drive)

I'd imaging I'd use Move-Item -destination "k:\My Documents\"

create a link or shortcut to the new file location.

I'm sure I will need more data at some point. I will take any/all the help I can get.

```
$Directory = Get-ChildItem "D:\Download" #Directory I care about
$SizeLimit = "200000" #Size limit in bytes

foreach ($File in $Directory) {
if ($File.Length -ge $SizeLimit) {
    # Notify the user with a pop-up
    # the coding for said popup

    # Move the file
    Move-Item $File.FullName K:\
    mklink.exe K:\$File.Name $File.FullName
```

Comment: have you even tried to do it?